# Changing filename capitalization for files on a network drive requires permission from myself

Tags: windows-7, permissions, rename, network-drive, offline-files

Whenever I try to rename a file on a network drive by changing the capitalization, I get a popup error telling me that I can't rename the file without permission from my own account.

For example, I am unable to rename a file `sample_file.txt` to `Sample_File.txt`, but I *am* able to rename the file to `sample_file_2.txt` without any issue.

This only happens when changing filename capitalization. My account has full ownership permissions over every file on the drive, and I haven't had any issues changing filenames outside of capitalization.

**Why would I need permission from my own account to change filename capitalization?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue with offline files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/953945/you-cannot-rename-files-by-using-different-case-when-the-files-are-mad) in Windows 7 and Windows Vista.

The official workaround is to rename your file to a different name, then rename it again back to the original name with proper capitalization.

> ### [You cannot rename files by using different case when the files are made available offline in Windows Vista or in Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/953945/you-cannot-rename-files-by-using-different-case-when-the-files-are-mad)
>
> #### Action
>
> When files are made available offline in Windows Vista or in Windows
>   7, you cannot rename files by using different case.
>
> For example, you have a file that is named TEXT.txt, and you want to
>   rename it to text.txt. However, you will be denied if the file is made
>   available offline.
>
> #### Cause
>
> The Offline Files feature uses the client-side cache (CSC) database.  When the files are made available offline, the CSC database prevents users from changing the case of file names.
>
> #### Resolution
>
> To work around this issue, rename the file to another name, and then rename back with the changed letter case.
>
> For example, rename TEXT.txt to word.txt, and then rename word.txt to text.txt.